# Configured CMake to compile in C++20 but the executable compiles in C++17

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, c++17, c++20

I am trying to configure CMake to compile my C++ project using the C++20 standard, but it keeps compiling in C++17. My compiler settings in `CMakeLists.txt` are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3 FATAL_ERROR)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
option(OPTIMISER "Optimiser level 3" OFF)
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

I get the following output when setting up my build directory with CMake:

```
Configuring CMake files...
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.7") found components: Interpreter 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/niran90/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build
```

The following is a minimal example in my code that requires C++20 features (requires a `constexpr` `std::fill` function):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <class t_data_type, int array_size>
constexpr auto InitializeStaticArray(const t_data_type& _init_value)
{
  std::array<t_data_type, array_size> initialised_array;
  std::fill(initialised_array.begin(), initialised_array.end(), _init_value);
  return initialised_array;
}

int main()
{
  constexpr auto test = InitializeStaticArray<double, 3>(1.0); // This code does not compile.
}
```

After compiling and running my program, the output that I get for `__cplusplus` is `201709`. Can anyone point out what I might me doing wrong in setting up my `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Additional Outputs:**

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

$ cmake --version 
cmake version 3.21.3
```

**Edits:**
I have just upgraded my `gcc` and `g++` versions to `10.3.0` and I am still unable to compile with `C++20`.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
```

Comment: Does your code use any C++20 features? If so, does it compile? And does your compiler advertise C++20 support through that macro?

Comment: @NicolBolas I would like my code to use C++20 features, and I have added an example to the post. However, it does not compile. Could you elaborate on your last question? Are there different compiler-specific macros to invoke C++20 support from the compiler?

Comment: What I'm referring to is that compilers that don't fully support C++20 may not redefine `__cplusplus` to be C++20's value. To change that value might be interpreted to indicate full support for all of C++20's features, which the implementation may not yet support. Have you checked to see if a `constexpr std::fill` is advertised as a supported C++20 feature of your standard library?

Comment: You are compiling with gcc 9.3 which only has partial support for c++20: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PjvE8K8s6

Comment: @NicolBolas and @Frank I have just upgraded my `gcc` and `g++` versions to `10.3.0`. I am still having the same issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to compile using C++20 after upgrading to GCC version 11.1.0. Thank you @NicolBolas and @Frank for the insights :)